# Asp.Net MVC action based custom authorization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, authorization

I have a web application written in asp.net mvc with fluent nhibernate.

> Data hierarchy:  Post -> Category ->
>   Company
>
> User roles : user, admin

I try to find a architecture to develop custom authorization. A user can be member of multiple company. Also a user can be an admin of a company while he can be also just member of another company.

Also we want develop a custom  authorization based on controller, action or id of action. For example a user can be admin of just one category. 
Namely; in our future system there will be users, user groups in which users and groups is belong to a company. While custom authorization will be applied to them based on url (contoller/action/id).

any recommendation, useful links etc?

Comment: What is your question, exactly? (There's not even a question mark). For the plain tech, see `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` and the `OnAuthorization` override of `Controller`. The multi-tenant architecture you need is should probably be a separate, implementation-agnostic question.

Comment: @mnemosyn actually it is not a question. it is trying to gather information before architectural design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky actually - you may want to rethink the custom authorization and consider populating the roles in say Application_AuthenticateRequest, and then use the [Authorize] attribute to do the actual checks if the user belongs to those roles.This way you are applying it directly to the action method and avoiding a custom mess but achieving basically the same result.

we are having a similar discussion not yet resolved at:
[Questions about a Custom Security setup for MVC3 using overridden AuthorizeAttribute, thread safety, ChildActions and caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074424/questions-about-a-custom-security-setup-for-mvc3-using-overriden-authorizeattribu/6172655#comment-7227727)